# Table in PHP with flatfile database

Tags: php, html, html-table, flat-file

I'm trying to display the content of a text file in table format, with two columns and four rows:

```
Mateo;Pérez
Marcos;Martínez
Lucas;Télez
Juan;Pez
```

This is the PHP I'm using but the result is not the desired:

```
<?php

$course = file_get_contents("course.txt");
$line = explode("\n", $course);
for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {
    $item = explode(";", $line[$i]);
    {echo"

<table border='1' style='width:100%'>
  <tr>
    <td>".$item[0]."</td>
    <td>".$item[1]."</td>
  </tr>

</table>

";
    }
}
?>
```

This is what i get:

[image]

Comment: Gotta love how there are 10 of the same answers below.

Comment: Could someone tellme how the hell should I remove the last row which is actually empty??? I do not know why it appears.

Comment: put in `for($i = 0; i < count($line) - 1; $i++)` instead of `for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++)`, because the arrays size is, for instance 3, so your for loop will go 4 times (0, 1, 2, 3), instead of 3 times that it needs to (0, 1, 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want.

```
<?php

$course = file_get_contents("course.txt");
$line = explode("\n", $course);

echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";

for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) 
{
    $item = explode(";", $line[$i]);
    {
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>".$item[0]."</td>
        <td>".$item[1]."</td>
    </tr>
    ";
    }
}

echo "</table>"

?>
```

The problem you has is that you were looping the table as well as the TR and TD tags. So basically you had multiple tables, instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php

    $course = file_get_contents("course.txt");
        $line = explode("\n", $course);
    ?>        
   <table border='1' style='width:100%'>
   <?php
    for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {
            $item = explode(";", $line[$i]);
            {echo"


      <tr>
        <td>".$item[0]."</td>
        <td>".$item[1]."</td>
      </tr>



    ";
            }
        }?>
   <?php
    </table>
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border='1' style='width:100%'>
<?php

$course = file_get_contents("course.txt");
    $line = explode("\n", $course);
    for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {
        $item = explode(";", $line[$i]);
        {echo"


  <tr>
    <td>".$item[0]."</td>
    <td>".$item[1]."</td>
  </tr>";
    }
}

?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html was not structured for desired result . Also try to make clear codes .. Try this-

```
<table border='1' style='width:100%'>
<?php

$course = file_get_contents("course.txt");
    $line = explode("\n", $course);
    for($i = 0; $i<count($line); $i++) {
        $item = explode(";", $line[$i]);
        {
?>


  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $item[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item[1]; ?></td>
  </tr>



<?php
        }
    }

?>
</table>
```